# C Exploit using Environment Variable in execve

Tags: stack, environment-variables, exploit, execv

In C programming language, for execve:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[],
                  char *const envp[]);
```

How can we use envp for exploiting?

Secondly, when passing values through envp, do we need to terminate it with a NULL?

Lastly, where is envp placed on stack?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of exploit do you mean? Any kind of exploit? Security flaw?

Comment: I want to open /bin/sh using a shellcode. Assume I know the location of return address on the stack and I have the shell code and I have to use envp to exploit it.

Comment: Is there any other thing you want to ask about the question?

Comment: No. I think that's a difficult question, and a limited number of people who knows that.

Answer (score 0):

Shellcode on Linux tends to use syscalls to exec. Are you perhaps thinking of ret2libc? Your question is mixing c code and shellcode and its not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This example could help you understand the usage of execve() argv and envp

*$ cat a.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "value of PWDIR is $PWDIR"
echo "first arg = $1"
echo "second arg = $2"
printenv
```

/* execve.c */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *newargv[] = { NULL, "hello", "world", NULL };
    char *newenviron[] = {"PWDIR=/home/root" };

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file-to-exec>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newargv[0] = argv[1];

    execve(argv[1], newargv, newenviron);
    perror("execve");   /* execve() only returns on error */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Compiling the code

$ cc execve.c -o execve

Executing the code and output as follows

```
$ ./execve a.sh
value of PWDIR is /home/root
first arg = hello
second arg = world
PWDIR=/home/root
PWD=/home/arul/work/images/samples
```

Environment variable passed in execve is used in the shell script.
Also note when script is executed, separate shell will be spawned here.

Answer (score 0):

When using `system()`, the program will use a shell to execute the command. So `system()` is vulnerable to command injection. Something like inserting

```
MY_ENV_VAR=`touch /tmp/test`
```

`execve()` on the other hand, doesn't use a shell. So you can't use `envp` to execute commands.

See also
https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177.